# onbeforeunload function works in IE not in Mozilla why?

Tags: javascript

I am using **onbeforeunload** function to alert the user before he closes his browser window. This works in IE, but not in Mozilla..is there any solution for this? Or with the help of jquery can we attain it?

Thanks in advance
Sooraj

Comment: Works fine: http://jsbin.com/ehuvo3

Comment: Please give an example of the code you are using that doesn't work.  Also, what version of Mozilla?

Comment: hi Bob, I am using version 3.6

Comment: Hi Crescent Fresh , ur example is working fine, but I want to show the alert only when the user closes the tab or try to close the whole browser...is it possible? Now problem is that the alert is coming for each links in the same page

Answer (score 0):

I think nicholas zakas can help you with this.
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2006/03/01/firefox-onbeforeunload-fun/

Comment: hi trelston, thanks for the link...in it I found like "So Kevin correctly pointed out that you can do the same onbeforeunload behavior in Firefox as you can in Internet Explorer. It does require a little bit of a tweak to use the DOM event model,"  but how?